# add class to parent li if dropdown is visible

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty standard CSS based dropdown menu. The main list is "#mainNav" and the dropdown is simply "mainNav ul". "mainNav ul" initially has a display of none, and when you hover over it's parent li, its display is set to block. When the nested ul is visible, i want to add the class "hilite" (this is the same as the a:hover attribute). so the parent li is highlighted when the dropdown is visible.

Targeting the `li` when the nested `ul` is visible:

```
$(function(){
    if($('#mainNav ul').css({display: "block"})){
        $("#mainNav li:nth-child(3)").addClass("hilite");
    }
});
```

the html

```
<ul id="mainNav" class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="contact.php" target="_self">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.php" target="_self">EVENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="current-line.php" target="_self">CURRENT LINE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">2009 Fall</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">2009 Spring</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">2008 Fall</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">2008 Spring</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="shop.php" target="_self">SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="press.php" target="_self">PRESS</a></li>
        <li><a href="bio.php" target="_self">BIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php" target="_self">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something along the lines of:

```
$("#mainNav ul li ul").hover(
  function(){ // Mouse Over
   $(this).parent().addClass("hilite");
  },
  function(){ // Mouse Out
    $(this).parent().removeClass("hilite");
  }
);
```

Comment: I modified the above to this ("#mainNav ul") to simply target the nested ul, then changed the css to this "ul#mainNav li.hilite > a" as I was only able to target the parent li, not the 'a' inside the li' and it works. Is there a cleaner way or a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: I have tried several different methods and always seem to end up right back to this. If you find something let me know, I'm always wanting to learn new methods.